# R10 Error when deploying a Docker image to Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

I faced some teething issue when trying to deploy my Docker image which contains a simple streamlit app to Heroku. My issue is that I am unable to access my Docker after deployment. On closer look, I discovered the following error:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

I had researched and understood that this is because the port is unavailable, since Heroku will dynamically assign port number.

I had made sure that this will not happen by putting the following my Dockerfile.

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install streamlit
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit","run", "--server.enableCORS", "false" ,"--server.port", "$PORT"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

I am now able to see that the Network URL and External URL port number are assigned by Heroku as it is not the typical 5901 number.

What puzzled me, however, is why is the container unable to bind to the given dynamic port number? I thought the app would be using the given dynamic number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$PORT` does not get replaced with the corresponding environment variable when the Docker run is executed on the Heroku Docker Registry.

An alternative is to create a Docker file which invokes .sh script

```
FROM python:3.7 
COPY . /app 
WORKDIR /app 
RUN pip install streamlit


ENTRYPOINT "/startup.sh"
```

and the startup.sh

```
echo PORT $PORT
streamlit run --server.enableCORS false --server.port $PORT app.py
```

Comment: solution tested works without ENTRYPOINTUSER as it does not exist in dockerfile.